# Memory Error on QGIS rastercalculator from console

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am experiencing a weird problem using QGIS on Mac.

I have been using RasterCalculator from the python console until yesterday without any problem, but yesterday my QGIS crashed while running a script (well, actually the whole computer crashed), and since then rastercalculator from the consol does not work any longer.

Whatever operation i do, even the most basic ones, return 5 = MemoryError.

Note that RasterCalculator still work without problems if I run it from the raster menu.

I tried to reinstall QGIS twice, but it didn't help.

it looks like something got broken with the crash, or some cache got filled up..

Any idea how to solve this issue?